# Standard sizeof macro for primitive types

Tags: c++11, macros, standards, sizeof, primitive

Are there any standard macros that can be used to identify the size of a primitive type at compile time? Similar to the ones in GCC:

```
__SIZEOF_INT__
__SIZEOF_LONG__
__SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__
__SIZEOF_SHORT__
__SIZEOF_POINTER__
__SIZEOF_FLOAT__
__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__
__SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__
__SIZEOF_SIZE_T__
```

I remember seeing something similar somewhere but for the death of me I can't find or remember their name anymore. The one I'm interested mostly is the long type.

Comment: There is no std macro for determining primitive type size.  I suppose you could implement one using the limit macros.  Based  on the max/min values, you would know the type size.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: In principle, numeric types could have padding bits that aren't reflected in their ranges.

Comment: What's wrong with `sizeof`?

Comment: @melak47: Presumably, the fact that it's not available at compile-time. Although It's fine as part of a constant expression, so I also wonder what the need is.

Comment: I was confused for a second. I don't usually have to make the distinction between preprocessing- and post-preprocessing compile-time :)

Comment: sizeof will not work at preprocessing phase

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard macro definitions for sizes of primitive types.

In boost/atomic there are macros giving you sizes of primitive types, they are using boost/cstdint.hpp among other sources. Example would look like follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_SIZEOF_LONG;
}
```

reference:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/atomic/detail/int_sizes.hpp